# Initializing an NSDisctionary dynamically

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

Whatup. I'm trying to use a `NSMutableDictionary` here, with a method `checkNull` that initializes the dictionary with some default values, if it is not set. However, the iOS simulator crashes at the first encounter in the `for`-loop.

Error message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Code:

```
+ (void)checkNull {
    if ([[self defaults] valueForKey:@"channels"] == nil) {
        NSNumber *defaultValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
        NSMutableDictionary *channels = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (NSString *channel in [self channelsList]) {
            [channels setObject:[defaultValue mutableCopy] forKey:channel];
        }
        [[self defaults] setValue:channels forKey:@"channels"];
    }
}
```

`[self defaults]` returns `[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]`, while
`[self channelsList]` returns an `NSArray` with around 10 `NSString` objects.

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSNumber doesn't respond to `mutableCopy`.

Why are you trying to, anyway? They are effectively singleton objects (in fact for low numbers they literally are singletons).

Also, you don't need to turn BOOL into NSNumber anymore, there are literals you can use.

```
+ (void)checkNull {
    if ([[self defaults] valueForKey:@"channels"] == nil) {
        NSMutableDictionary *channels = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (NSString *channel in [self channelsList]) {
            [channels setObject:@YES forKey:channel];
        }
        [[self defaults] setValue:channels forKey:@"channels"];
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. I think I misunderstood the idea of `mutableCopy` just a bit. Thank you.